# UIScrollView with Paging and new View Controllers

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, paging

I currently have an app that has a UIScrollView with paging as the primary ViewController. However, currently, I am trying to animate to a new ViewController, but whenever I use presentModalViewController or an animation using UIView, I am still able to scroll, left and right on the original view.

I was successfully able to keep it from scrolling by adding it to the window:

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [window addSubview:NEWVIEW.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

However, after using this code, I was uncertain of how to return to the original scrollView.

Thank You for any help you can provide.

Comment: I wanted to add something else. There are 5 view controllers in the uiscrollview, when i try to animate or modalview, I am only doing one. I believe that that is the problem, but I am not sure of the proper way to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
I fixed this problem by putting all of my viewcontrollers into one xib file. I set then all up as IBOutlets and then modalViewController worked just fine.